# Case sensitive replace for case insensitive search with regex

Tags: regex, case

Ok so I doing the following regex replace:

```
 Input: ([Ll])ocation
Output: \1abel
```

That replaces `Location` with `Label` and `location` with `label`. However, if I want to replace `location` with `geocode` and `Location` with `Geocode`, can I do that with a single regex?

I'm doing a search and replace in notepad++ at the moment, but I've had this problem in multiple regex dialects.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do two separate case-sensitive replaces?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$str1 = 'Location Loc10';
$str2 = 'location Loc10';

$str1 =~ s/(L(?{ $g = 'G'; }) | l(?{ $g = 'g'; }) )ocation/${g}eocode/x;
print "$str1\n"; # prints Geocode Loc10

$str2 =~ s/(L(?{ $g = 'G'; }) | l(?{ $g = 'g'; }) )ocation/${g}eocode/x;
print "$str2\n"; # prints geocode Loc10
```

**N.B.** This piece of code uses experimental 'evaluate any Perl code' zero-width assertion. It is here only because you asked about it, I would **not** recommend using such expressions, it is much better to do several replaces. And I really doubt that Notepad++ supports it.

Answer (score 1):

[EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) will do that if you select the "Adapt Case" option while replacing.  It's not really a regex feature, just a feature that's supported by some tools that do search and replace.  Said tools are usually powered by regexes, but that's not required; in fact, I don't think regexes would be much help in implementing such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
echo Location | perl -pe 's/(l)ocation/$1^lc($1)^"geocode"/ei'
Geocode
```